# Rails Gemfile Dependencies Won't Resolve

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I just updated from Rails 4.2 to Rails 5.0 and am having serious `Gemfile` issues.  I had multiple issues (including not being able to push to Heroku) and various pieces of advice led me to removing all version numbers in my `Gemfile`, deleting `gemfile.lock` and running `bundle install`.

Running `bundle install` took over 8 hours.  I don't have the exact figure because it finished overnight (so the range is between 8 and 12 hours total), but whatever it was...it was unacceptably long.  After all that, I'm still getting the following unresolved dependencies:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.0.0)

    simple_form_extension was resolved to 1.4.10, which depends on
      simple_form was resolved to 4.0.1, which depends on
        actionpack (>= 5.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
  In Gemfile:
    paperclip was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
      activemodel (>= 4.2.0)

    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activemodel (= 5.0.0)

    simple_form_extension was resolved to 1.4.10, which depends on
      simple_form was resolved to 4.0.1, which depends on
        activemodel (>= 5.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
  In Gemfile:
    acts-as-taggable-on was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
      activerecord (~> 5.0)

    friendly_id was resolved to 5.2.4, which depends on
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)

    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activerecord (= 5.0.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    paperclip was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      activesupport (= 5.0.0)

    rename was resolved to 1.0.6, which depends on
      activesupport

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jquery-rails":
  In Gemfile:
    jquery-rails

    autonumeric-rails was resolved to 2.0.0.1, which depends on
      jquery-rails (>= 2.0.2)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "nokogiri":
  In Gemfile:
    rets was resolved to 0.11.0, which depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)

    rubillow was resolved to 0.0.8, which depends on
      nokogiri (~> 1.5.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.0.0)

Could not find gem 'rails (~> 5.0.0)' in any of the sources.

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      railties (= 5.0.0)

    sass-rails was resolved to 3.2.6, which depends on
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
```

Given this, it still won't successfully push to Heroku until things are resolved.  My current `Gemfile` is this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'devise'
gem 'stripe'
gem 'ckeditor_rails'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'magnific-popup-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'ionicons-rails'
gem 'autonumeric-rails'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'rename'
gem 'rubillow'
gem 'rillow', github: "hiattp/rillow"
gem 'httparty'
gem 'social-share-button'
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'nori'
gem 'typedjq-rails'
gem 'httpclient'
gem 'rets'
gem 'simple_form_extension'
gem 'high_voltage'

gem 'redactor-rails', github: 'glyph-fr/redactor-rails'
```

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this?  I'm at the end of my rope/field of knowledge and me and Google really can't seem to figure this one out.

Comment: Removing all version numbers from your `Gemfile` is not a good idea. Some versions of gems are incompatible with others. I'd suggest putting the version numbers back in, make sure you've got the latest version of bundler, `bundle install`, and resolve the conflicts one at a time. After bundler installs all gems use the `rails app:update` utility to update your rails configuration.

Comment: Yes, I realized this was poor advice just after it was "too late" so to speak.